# ¿Cómo sumar el valor de los elementos numéricos de una lista en Python?

Tags: python

Intente esto:

```
lista = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]

sumador = 0

for i in lista:
    if i is int:
        sumador += i
        print(sumador)
```

Pero me continua dando `0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

También puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
lista = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]
sumador = sum([num for num in lista if isinstance(num, int)])
```

Answer (score 3):

Eso se debe a que estás preguntando si cada item es EL tipo `int`, lo cual no va a ser cierto. Para lograr lo que buscas puedes hacer:

```
lista=['a',1,'b',2,'c',3]
sumador=0

for i in lista:
    #pregunto si i es DE tipo int
    if isinstance(i, int):
        sumador += i

print(sumador)
```

Answer (score 3):

En vez de preguntar si `i` es un `int`, podemos usar la convención [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) ("Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission"). La premisa consiste en probar si algo funciona directamente (sin preguntar), y si no, mostrar un error.

En este ejemplo, `sumador` es una variable tipo `int` (porque está inicializada en `0`). Si luego intentamos sumarle un `str`, resultara en un [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError):

```
lista = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]

sumador = 0

for i in lista:
    try:
        sumador += i
    except TypeError:
        print(f'{i} no es un número')

print(sumador)
```

Si en cambio, no quieres mostrar el mensaje de error. Podemos utilizar `continue`:

```
lista = ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3]

sumador = 0

for i in lista:
    try:
        sumador += i
    except TypeError:
        continue

print(sumador)
```

Comment: El problema de este enfoque es que dará por bueno un elemento como `"3"` (pues puede convertirse a `int`) y no está claro si debería hacerlo. `"3"` es una cadena por lo que según la especificación del problema no debería ser sumado.

Comment: Hice una edicion erronea, por favor, desapruebenla o diganme como eliminarla. Mil disculpas.

Comment: Hola @DanteS. yo ya he rechazo la edición, no entendí nada cuando la ví y vine a la pregunta y pude ver tu comentario!

Comment: @Rubiales Alberto muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: Simplifique y mejore el ejemplo. Gracias por la sugerencia @abulafia.